# Set Mouse.OverrideCursor to drag cursor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'd like to set the override cursor to the cursor that appears when an item is dragged, however it doesn't exist in the Cursors enum and I haven't been able to find a reliable way of accessing it via reflection.

Here's one of the approaches I've tried:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var cursorStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SimplestDragDrop.DDIcon.cur");
var cursor = new Cursor(cursorStream);
Mouse.OverrideCursor = cursor;
```

Comment: you may want to read more about wpf drag and drop https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Steve I appreciate the reference, however, I am not doing a standard drag and drop operation here. I just want to access the drag cursor.

Comment: Just find that cursor icon as png and add it to your project resources. From thee you can use it as a custom cursor. Only thing about this approach is that the cursor will stay as is when you use a theme for windows optics.